# I want to pass value from aspx.cs page to master page

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a master page in that page i want to show the user name in a label . but i want to pass the value on that label from .cs page. My page is also  connected to the master page. please help me how can i do that.

Comment: post your codes then people can understand the question easily and answer easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with the below code in your content page.aspx.cs.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     Label lblMasterPage= this.Master.FindControl("lblMasterPage") as Label;
     lblMasterPage.Text = "Setting Label from Content Page";
}
```

Note : use your master page label id instead of lblMasterPage.

Hope this helps!

Comment: same like that I have  <li id="Adduser"><a href="AddAgent.aspx">Add User</a></li> and this code is in master page  and I want to pass value from my .cs page with help of id =Adduser .how can i do that.?

Comment: Adduser is in master page?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Sessions...
Session["Session Name"]= someValues; 
You can assign a value to session and show it on master page with the help of textbox or lbl etc